# How to pass sql query with . in name - Javascript/Node.JS - Alexa App

Tags: javascript, node.js, alexa-skills-kit

Good Day,

I am trying to have Alexa say the results of a SQOL query, but I receive an error every-time try to include owner.name in the output.

`this.t("CASEINFO",resp.records[0]._fields.casenumber, resp.records[0]._fields.subject,resp.records[0]._fields.priority,resp.records[0]._fields.owner.name);`

. I believe this is because it has a "." in the name, but I am not sure how to escape the period so it reads it correctly.

Note if I don't put `"resp.records[0]._fields.owner.name"` into the script, everything works without issue.  I know, this is the reason for the error.

This what I have tried...

1) `this.t("CASEINFO",resp.records[0]._fields.casenumber, resp.records[0]._fields.subject,resp.records[0]._fields.priority,resp.records[0]._fields.[owner.name]);`

2) `this.t("CASEINFO",resp.records[0]._fields.casenumber, resp.records[0]._fields.subject,resp.records[0]._fields.priority,resp.records[0]._fields.owner//.name);`

3)putting into a var (var casenumber = owner.name) and then using casenumber in the query.

Any help would be appreciated.

````
'CaseInformation': function () {
 console.log("CaseInformation function");
 if (preFunctions.call(this)) {
   //const OwnerName = getSlotValue(this.event.request.intent.slots.caseowner_name.value);
   var CaseInfo = this.event.request.intent.slots.case_info.value;
   console.log(`CaseInfo: ${CaseInfo}`);
   const accessToken = this.event.session.user.accessToken;
   sf.query("select casenumber,subject, owner.name, status, priority, account.name, lastmodifieddate from case where casenumber='" + CaseInfo + "'", accessToken, (err, resp) => {
 if (resp.records!="") {
       if (resp.records) {
         const output = this.t("CASEINFO",resp.records[0]._fields.casenumber, resp.records[0]._fields.subject,resp.records[0]._fields.priority,resp.records[0]._fields.owner.name);
         this.emit(":ask", output, this.t("PROMPT")); ```
````

Answer (score 0):

Square bracket notation:

```
this.t("CASEINFO",resp.records[0]._fields.casenumber, resp.records[0]._fields.subject,resp.records[0]._fields.priority,resp.records[0]._fields["owner.name"]);
```